# Show that $(x_n-y_n)$ converges to $x-y$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Given $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are sequences of real number which converge to $x$ and $y$ respectively. Show that $(x_n-y_n)$ converges to $x-y$.

If it's asking about $(x_n+y_n)$. I know that I can use triangle inequality, but can I also use triangle inequality here? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Show that the sequence $(-y_n)$ converges to $-y$ and the identity

$$
x_n-y_n=x_n+(-y_n).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes: 
$$|(x_n-y_n)-(x-y)|=|(x_n-x)-(y_n-y)|\le|x_n-x|+|y_n-y|\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same triangle inequality

- $|x_{n}-y_{n}| = |x_{n} + (-y_{n})|$

Comment: This expression will not help to prove convergence to $x-y$. The best you can hope to get from a triangle inequality on this expression is boundedness of the sequence $\{x_n-y_n\}_n$